# Refresh a ListView adding new elements on runtime in NativeScript and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I'm building a ListView based component, similar to the groceries example in the {N} page. I have a "+" button, that needs to add new items to the list, I have this code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-list',
    templateUrl: 'my-list.component.html'
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    private myList: CustomObject;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    addItem(){
        this.myList.push(new CustomObject());
    }

}
```

And here is the template:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="+" (tap)="addItem()" ></Button>
    <ListView [items]="myList">
        <template let-item="item" let-i="i">
            <Label text="item.name"></Label>
        </template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

My problem is, when I click on the "+" button, I get an undescifrable exception. When I fill the list with code, no problem, but I need the user can add new elements to the view. How is the correct way to implement a dynamic ListView like I described?

EDIT:

> An uncaught Exception ocurred on "main" thread.
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method getView failded
>
> Error No suitable views found in list template! Nesting level:0 File:
>   "/data/data/org.nativescript.MyApp/files/app/tns_moudules/nativescript-angular/directives/list-view-comp.js,
>   line:135 column:8
>
> StackTrace: Frame: function:'getSingleViewRecursive', file:....

Comment: What do you mean with  "undescifrable"? To  undescifrable to be able to post it here?

Comment: I mean there are a lot of lines on the StackTrace referencing to .js files. I post the first lines (for some reason I can't copy all the exception on the clipboard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NativeScript + Angular-2 application you can use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html)

Example on how to provide data via async pipe in NativeScript + NG2 app can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ui-category/listview/using-async-pipe)

What is noticeable is the usage of **RxObservable**

***page.component.ts***

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable as RxObservable } from "rxjs/Observable";

export class DataItem {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: "ui-category/listview/using-async-pipe/using-async-pipe.component.html",
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class UsingAsyncPipeComponent {
    public myItems: RxObservable<Array<DataItem>>;

    constructor() {
        let items = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            items.push(new DataItem(i, "data item " + i));
        }

        let subscr;
        this.myItems = RxObservable.create(subscriber => {
            subscr = subscriber;
            subscriber.next(items);
            return function () {
                console.log("Unsubscribe called!");
            };
        });

        let counter = 2;
        let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            counter++;
            items.push(new DataItem(counter + 1, "data item " + (counter + 1)));
            subscr.next(items);
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }, 15000);
    }
}
```

***page.component.html***

```
<ListView [items]="myItems | async" class="list-group">
    <template let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
        <GridLayout class="list-group-item" [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even">
            <Label [text]="item.name" android:class="label-item"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </template>
</ListView>
```

In this basic example the async is simulated with setInterval but based on the same logic you can achieve your desired UX with a button.

Comment: Tweeking this code a little, i achieved what I want. My problem now is that if I ad a custom component instead of a label in the template, I get the same exception. Is there any site where explains how this works? Thanks!