# Refresh label countdown in NativeScript and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm building a timer countdown component, here is the code:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'time-countdown',
  template: `<StackLayout>
                 <Label text="{{timeRemaining}}" ></Label>
             <StackLayout>`
})
export class TimeCountdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() periodDetails  :any; 
    private timeRemaining     :string = "";
    private units           :string = "";

    constructor( private ps: PeriodService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate = this.ps.getNextPeriod(this.periodDetails);
      console.log("TIME COUNTDOWN: init => " + this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate.toString() )
      setInterval(() => {
          this.getTimeRemaining()
      }, 1000)
    }           

    getTimeRemaining(){
      let trObject = this.ps.getTimeRemaining(this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate);
      this.timeRemaining = trObject.time;
      this.units = (!trObject.units) ? "days": "";
      console.log("TIME COUNTDOWN: Tick => " + this.timeRemaining )
    }          
  }
```

In the console I get the correct units and time remaining, but in the label is not showing. I tryed to use Observable.timer().subscribe, Observable.interval().subscribe, change the template to "[text]='timeRemaining'", but never shows.

This component is added dynamicaly by the user (related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887541/refresh-a-listview-adding-new-elements-on-runtime-in-nativescript-and-angular/40888469#40888469) post ). The thing is, when I click on the "+" button to add a new timer, the time is shown for a little fraction of second and then disapears again. Someone have any idea of what is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
After lots of research an tryes, if found an intermediate solution.If I use this component as the root component of the app, It works with this code:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'time-countdown',
  template: `
            <StackLayout>
              <Label [text]="timeRemaining | async" ></Label>
            <StackLayout>
            `
})

export class TimeCountdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() periodDetails: any;
    private timeRemaining: any;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate = this.ps.getNextPeriod(this.periodDetails);
        this.timeRemaining = new Observable<string>((observer: Subscriber<string>) => {
          setInterval(() => observer.next(this.getTimeRemaining().time),1000);
        });
    }


    constructor(private ps: PeriodService ) {}


    getTimeRemaining() {
        let tr = this.ps.getTimeRemaining(this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate);
        console.log(tr.time);
        return tr;
    }
}
```

But if I nest it into another component it don't works, the console shows the time remaining but in the template nothing is shown. Someone can make me understand whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an observable you need to use the async pipe `<Label [text]="timeRemaining | async" ></Label>` , if not you can use NgZone or zonedCallback

ZoneCallback

```
declare var zonedCallback: Function;

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'time-countdown',
    template: `<StackLayout>
                 <Label text="{{timeRemaining}}" ></Label>
             <StackLayout>`
})
export class TimeCountdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() periodDetails: any;
    private timeRemaining: string = "";
    private units: string = "";

    constructor(private ps: PeriodService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate = this.ps.getNextPeriod(this.periodDetails);
        console.log("TIME COUNTDOWN: init => " + this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate.toString())
        setInterval(() => {
            this.getTimeRemaining()
        }, 1000)
    }

    getTimeRemaining() {
        let trObject = this.ps.getTimeRemaining(this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate);
        zonedCallback(() => {
            this.timeRemaining = trObject.time;
            this.units = (!trObject.units) ? "days" : "";
        })
        console.log("TIME COUNTDOWN: Tick => " + this.timeRemaining)
    }
}
```

NgZone

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'time-countdown',
    template: `<StackLayout>
                 <Label text="{{timeRemaining}}" ></Label>
             <StackLayout>`
})
export class TimeCountdownComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() periodDetails: any;
    private timeRemaining: string = "";
    private units: string = "";

    constructor(private ps: PeriodService, private ngZone: NgZone) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate = this.ps.getNextPeriod(this.periodDetails);
        console.log("TIME COUNTDOWN: init => " + this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate.toString())
        setInterval(() => {
            this.getTimeRemaining()
        }, 1000)
    }

    getTimeRemaining() {
        let trObject = this.ps.getTimeRemaining(this.periodDetails.nextPeriodStartDate);
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.timeRemaining = trObject.time;
            this.units = (!trObject.units) ? "days" : "";
        })
        console.log("TIME COUNTDOWN: Tick => " + this.timeRemaining)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for respones but any of this work for me, using the observable with async pipe or the ZonedCallback don't shows anithing.If I use NgZone, the timer apears, but don't refresh, and if I add a new timer, the previous timer disapears, and the new is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You lost the context. Use "this" as in getTimeRemaining(this) to pass the context to method.